# How can i filter a given numpy array for a value and put the remaining values of the array into a new one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

i would like to know why this code doesnt work...
I dont know why it doesnt allow me to use the if condition in this case.

```
a = np.array(range(30)).reshape(3,10)
a[:,1] = -1 #random values set to -1
a[:,6] = -1
a[:,7] = -1
print(a)
b = []
for i in a:
    if i !=-1:
        b.append(True)
b --> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I would like to put the remaining values of a into b. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please add simple input and desired output...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because the element `i` in `a` is still a `numpy` array. The `!=` operator used in this way needs a single element, so to access these you need to put an additional layer `for j in i:` and then change the following line with `if j !=1:`. So for example

```
import numpy as np
​
a = np.array(range(30)).reshape(3,10)
a[:,1] = -1 #random values set to -1
a[:,6] = -1
a[:,7] = -1
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j !=-1:
            b.append(True)
```

This prints for `a`:

```
[[ 0 -1  2  3  4  5 -1 -1  8  9]
 [10 -1 12 13 14 15 -1 -1 18 19]
 [20 -1 22 23 24 25 -1 -1 28 29]]
```

And for `b` we get:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

As far as the goal of this code, I'm not sure what output you expect, but this is the error in terms of making it run.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that when you iterate through `a` in the for loop, what you're iterating through is not each element in `a`, but each sub-array.

If you add `print(len(a))`, you'll see that you're getting 3 as the result, not the expected 30. So, when you iterate through `a` (`i` being the sub-array within `a`) and then test to see if the value is `-1`, what you're asking python to do is to see if an array of `[0,-1,2,3,4,5,-1,-1,8,9]` is equal to -1. An array can't be equal to an integer because it's an array not an integer. That error is telling you that when it says:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

So, to answer your question, you *can* use `if` there, you you need to be comparing two like objects (ints to ints, strings to strings, etc.). You're trying to test if multiple values equal a single value and that's where python gets mad at you.

Your question is still a bit unclear as to what you want b to look like, but if you just want to return all the non -1 values in `a` in roughly the same shape as `a`, you could do a double for loop:

```
## Create blank output array
b = []

## First loop goes through the length of a, which will be 3, meaning we're iterating over each sub-array
for i in range(len(a)):
    ## Add a blank sub array to our output array
    b.append([])

    ## Start a second loop that iterates through each element in the sub-array, keyed to the current index in our loop through 0-2
    for x in a[i]:             ## a[i] in the first loop is a[0], a[1] in the second run, etc.
        if x != -1:
            gg[i].append(x)    ## Now append the value of x if it's not -1 to the sub-array we created at index i in b
    
print(b)
>>> [[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], [10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19], [20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29]]
```

There is also a much less ugly way to do this with list comprehension

```
b = [[y for y in x if y != -1] for x in a]

print(b)
>>> [[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], [10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19], [20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29]]
```